# python 3.5 - django 1.10 - mysqlclient windows 7 installation error

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have very disturbing me problem with configuring mysql in django.

I did it with python 3.5 and Django 1.10 on Ubuntu x64 but I can't do this on windows 7.

I tried almost everything, I hope almost:

- installed python 3.5
- installed pip for python
- upgrade everything what I can upgrade
- installed django
- installed visual studio 2015 for python 3.5
- installed mysql server and workbench
- installed all connectors for mysql C, python, odbc
- installed vs C++ Redistributable 2013
- installed mingw
- download mysqlclient 1.3.9
- trying to edit some files with information from stack
- more more stress and do things what I could do

So I had a lot of errors what I could pass and now I have one error (hope last) that I can't do anything with it.

when I use command: `python setup.py install` in folder with mysqlclient 1.3.9 I got error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\_mingw.h(49): fatal error C1189: #error:  ERROR: You must use a GNU Compiler.
```

I thought that it is problem with compiler from Visual Studio, so I try to use mingw as default gcc, it helped but with another error:

```
ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1900
```

I can't help myself with it and I hopeless now

Can somebody help me install mysqlclient on windows 7 wit python 3.5 to use it with django 1.10??

I repeat only that on Ubuntu it is worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the latest mysqlclient, you can grab a wheel from here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

install it with usual: `pip install path_to_wheel.whl`

And it should work. Doesn't look like the latest mysqlclient version adds a lot:

https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/HISTORY

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't know why but it was so simple working thing :)
thanks a lot for helping me in this disturbing situation
best man on stack (I think so)

Answer (score 2):

simply do this
   `pip install mysqlclient==1.3.9`

Comment: No, the same error like with normal pip install, or install from source package