# pip install MySQLdb is not working in my pc and some other errors

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, windows-10, django-1.10

I am using python-3.6.0 & windows10. During learning django I created a project and when I typed `python manage.py makemigrations` it began to show errors. I checked many Q/A. But nothing is working as there suggestion.

I tried `pip install mysqlclient`, `pip install MySQLdb` and some other commands.

Here is some screenshots

[image: mysqldb error in IDE]

[image: mysqldb error]

Now what can I do. Please need your help.

Comment: `MySQLdb` does not support Python 3, so you should use `mysqlclient` instead. Doing `pip install mysqlclient` does not always work on Windows, so one option is to install a pre-built wheel, as suggested in the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653187/python-3-5-django-1-10-mysqlclient-windows-7-installation-error).

Answer (score -1):

You need to install MySQL-python via pip

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: also tried that but finally it says

`_mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory`

Comment: `MySQL-python` is Python 2 only - the OP is using Python 3.